# How to convert this C type to a c# type

Tags: c#, c++, types

I have a type CK_NOTIFY in C++ defined as follows:

```
typedef uint ( * CK_NOTIFY)(
   uint   hSession,
   uint   event,
   void*  pApplication
);
```

I need to redefine this type in C# because I need to use it as an argument for a pinvoke function.
What is it exactly? A structure? Or a function pointer?

Comment: It's a function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a `delegate`.  Your "C type" is describing a function.

The function returns a `uint` and takes 2 `uints` and a `void*`.

So your delegate could look like:

```
Func<uint, uint, object, uint>
```

How you want to handle the `void*` is up to you...

Comment: Thanks, Ya, i think I ll make it Func<uint, uint, IntPtr>

Comment: That will return a `IntPtr` then... just fyi. The last type in a `Func<>` is the return type.

Comment: Ah! Dint know that. Thanks. So, in your case, how can i pass 4 args when I m calling the function? Or the uint is just used to hold the returned value?

Comment: So the last type is used to hold the return value.  So lets say you had `Func<uint, uint, object, uint>()f = ...`, you would call `f` with `f(0,1,null)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need that for interop (ie. passing it to an unmanaged DLL), you want a delegate declaration like this:

```
public delegate uint CK_NOTIFY(uint hSession, uint @event, System.IntPtr pApplication);
```

Comment: why is there an '@' for event? Also, I noticed on the C++ side, event was in blue (a keyword)  unlike the other 2 args

Comment: @TylerDurden That's related :) Basically, `@` allows you to use a word which is a keyword (`event` is such a keyword in C#) and use it as an identifier.

Comment: Like how TylerDurden is a keyword in ur above comment ;)